# Node.js files never work

Tags: node.js

I am having a difficult time getting the most basic things done on Node.js. I'm pretty sure it's installed right but I could be wrong. If anyone could help because I'm clueless. I have saved this file like the online tutorial suggest but when I try to execute it in Node.js it always gives me errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
hello.js
```

> ```
> ReferenceError: hello is not defined
>     at repl:1:1
>     at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
>     at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:73:12)
>     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
>     at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:340:29)
>     at bound (domain.js:280:14)
>     at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
>     at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
>     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
>     at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
> ```

```
node hello.js
node hello.js
     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Are you opening it in repl
Do `node hello.js`

Comment: Yes I have been doing that but nothing works. I have tried in several ways in the command prompt, node.js command prompt and I always get some error.

Comment: What is hello.js
Can u post that as well